# How to update pip on EMR notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

Am trying to update pip on EMR notebook, `sc.install_pypi_package` seems to install an older version, I also tried

```
import os
cmd = 'pip install --upgrade pip'
print(os.system(cmd))
```

but doesn't seem to work

Comment: doesn't seem to work - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Answer (score 2):

I did it by un-installing and re-installing a newer version

```
sc.uninstall_package('pip')
sc.install_pypi_package("pip==22.2.2")
```

Comment: The second line only needs to be `sc.install_pypi_package("pip")` and it will default to the latest version.